# Vue, Send a GET request with the header configuration to the server in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, request, http-headers, request-headers

I would like to send an GET request to a server with the following header when the component is being created in a vue js component:

How should I write this request?

> curl:
>
> -X GET "http://134.140.154.121:7075/rest/api/Time" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkFZd21VU0Jvd2lxcVRSRG81NTctVFEiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1OTMfryyw"

And the information it sends is as follows:

> Response body:
>
> {
> "values": {
> "value": "string"
> }
> }

How do I send header and outh settings along with the request?

Answer (score 1):

```
  fetch("http://134.140.154.121:7075/rest/api/Time",{
        method:'GET',
        header:{
             'accept': 'application/json',
             'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkFZd21VU0Jvd2lxcVRSRG81NTctVFEiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1OTMfryyw'
        }
    })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
      // Use res
}
```